# If $f(n)=n^a$ for a given $a>0$, find $g(n)$ such that $f(n)\notin O(g(n))$ and $f(n)\notin \Omega (g(n))$

Tags: complexity-theory

If $f(n)=n^a$ for a given $a>0$, I need to find a function $g(n)$ such that $f(n)\notin O(g(n))$ and $f(n)\notin \Omega (g(n))$.

I am not sure how to find such function, which satisfies both of the conditions.

Answer (score 1):

For given $a>0$ and $f(n)=n^a$ we consider
$$g(n)= \begin{cases}{}
n^{a+1}, & n=2k\\ 
0, & n=2k-1
\end{cases}$$
for $k\in \mathbb{N}$